# Inserting into 2 tables select result of a table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to insert into 2 tables result from a select statement.

I have a table with several data:

```
val1 val2 val3 .... valn
-------------------------
 12   21   54        78
 ..   ..    ..       ..
```

I have something like: 
`Select t1.val1, t1.val2, t2.val3, t2.val4 into table1 t1 , table2 t2 from tablename.`

So I want val1, val2, being inserted into a new table with 2 fields like:

```
tabble1:
id fieldvalue
1   val1
2   val2
```

the same goes to val3 and val4. How can this be acomplished

```
tabble2:
id fieldvalue
1   val3
2   val4
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It cannot - not in a single SQL statement. An `INSERT` is always into a single table - if you need to fill two tables, you need two statements.

Comment: Are you trying to normalize an existing table?

Comment: Not really, just splitting some of their attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granted, it is difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish. If you are in fact trying to insert rows into two different tables, as marc_s stated, you must use two insert statements.

However, judging from your sample, it may not be the case that you are trying to insert into two tables but rather use two tables to insert into a third table where you transpose the data. If that is the case, then you can do it in a single statement:

```
Insert MysteryTable( Id, fieldvalue )
Select 1, val1
From Table1
Union All
Select 2, val2
From Table1
Union All
Select 3, val3
From Table2 --assuming these come from Table2. Isn't clear in the OP
Union All
Select 4, val4
From Table2 --assuming these come from Table2. Isn't clear in the OP
```

Of course, if Table1 or Table2 has many rows, then you will obviously get many rows with the same Id value in your MysteryTable.

**Update given change to OP**

Given your clarification, what you seek can be done but requires two queries similar to the one above.

```
Insert Table1( Id, fieldvalue )
Select 1, val1
From SourceTable
Union All
Select 2, val2
From SourceTable

Insert Table2( Id, fieldvalue )
Select 1, val3
From SourceTable
Union All
Select 2, val4
From SourceTable
```

Another variation which generates your id values would be:

```
With NumberedItems As
    (
    Select val1 As val
    From SourceTable
    Union All
    Select val2
    From SourceTable
    )
Insert Table1(id, fieldname)
Select Row_Number() Over( Order By val ) As Num
    , val
From SourceTable

With NumberedItems As
    (
    Select val3 As val
    From SourceTable
    Union All
    Select val4
    From SourceTable
    )
Insert Table2(id, fieldname)
Select Row_Number() Over( Order By val ) As Num
    , val
From SourceTable
```

Btw, in the above example, I used `Union All`, however if you are trying to normalize the data, you might want to have distinct values. In that case, you would use `Union` instead of `Union All`.

Comment: Excuse me @Thomas,What would be the way to aply your solution when I have multiple column values, like, val1,val2,val3,val4....valn
I know dynamic sql could be use, but How?

Comment: Which of your 2 solutions would be simpler to implement for dynamic sql?

Comment: @darkcminor - Since you are doing this in a middle-tier component (right?), it is really a push. The advantage of the second solution is that it will automatically create sequential numbers for you assuming that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a single insert statement that creates two rows from 1 column and have the values come from different columns.

Just create one insert statement per column like so assuming that the id field is an auto incrementing column.

```
insert into table1 (fieldname)
select val1 from tableName

insert into table1 (fieldname)
select val2 from tableName

insert into table1 (fieldname)
select val3 from tableName

insert into table1 (fieldname)
select val4 from tableName
```

Comment: those aren't update statements, as you call them - those are INSERT statements. And in this case, you could very well write `INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2, field3, field4) SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4 from otherTable`...

Comment: Oops, yeah, I meant insert. I think he wants the column "fieldname" filled with the contents of all four columns which is why you need the four insert statements.

Comment: Hi I edited a bit the question.. you can not use alias to insert in 2 different tables the select result from a table like in the question? right?